# How to remove shower drain cover

Tags: bathroom, shower, drain, bathroom-fixtures

Right, I've recently moved into a new flat in London and it's time the drain was unblocked but I just cannot figure out how to take the drain cover off. If someone could let me know so I don't end trying to force it out and possibly breaking it in the process, that would be great.

I've Googled 'how to remove a drain cover' but there seems like so many types and I have no idea which mine is.

Here's a couple of pictures of the type of drain cover in question.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried unscrewing it ACW? How does the drain close?

Comment: I've tried screwing both ways, nothing seems to happen. It also doesn't close as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one very similar to that.  It lifts out vertically.

There are six keyed slots in the drain tube that the cover slots into.  So you have to lift it keeping it level.  Place something under two sides of the cover and lift together, if you only lift from one side it will twist and won't come out.

There will then be a plastic hair trap guard that just lifts out easily that you can clean.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried lifting from both sides but it just bends slightly and I'm scared to pull it any harder in case I break it. The whole thing twists already so does that mean it won't come out? I can sort of see the six slots you're talking about if I get right down and lift one side up.

Comment: Nevermind! I've done it. Turns out I just had to keep pulling and wiggling it a bit. Thanks for your help and information.